# Collapse and Expand the View Bar in visual studio code shortcut key

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut key to collapse and expand the view bar *(the left vertical menu)* in visual studio code?

With the mouse, I can do that, by click any item twice in the view bar such as **Explorer**, **Search**, **SCM** etc, and the view bar collapses.

How to do that using keyboard?

The following shows expanded and then collapsed.

[image: View bar expanded in Visual Studio Code]

[image: View bar collapsed in Visual Studio Code]

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to archieve this using `Ctrl + B`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom key-binding in VS Code *(on windows)*.

> To open keyboard shortcuts, use `ctrl + k, ctrl + s`.

If you want to **toggle Activity Bar visibility** `ctrl+alt+\`.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+oem_5",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleActivityBarVisibility"
},
```

If you want to **toggle Sidebar visibility** `ctrl+\`.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+oem_5",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility"
},
```